# rsync is writing incomplete logs

Tags: linux, rsync, cron

I have a cronjob to perform copy on a directory to different folders every week. I use RSYNC to perform the copy as it has a parameter to write the job progress to a log file. Basically below is how the cron goes.

```
00 23 15 * *     rsync --log-file=/mnt/Week3/copy.log -rv /[folder_name]/ /mnt/Week3 2>&1
```

Copy works just as expected, but when I review the logs I can see incomplete entry of the job progress

```
[whois@serv1~]$ cat /mnt/Week3/copy.log
sending incremental file list
./
copy.log
folder/
folder/folder1/
folder/folder1/files1.dmp
[whois@serv1~]$ cd /mnt/Week3/
```

Those folders contains hundreds of files not only file1.dmp.

When I issue the exact same command directly instead of going trough cron, it's able to show the progress, I had to cancel as it'll take too long to complete.

```
[whois@serv1 ~]$ rsync --log-file=/mnt/Week3/copy.log -rv /folder/folder1/ /mnt/Week3 2>&1
sending incremental file list
copy.log
folder/folder1/file1.dmp
folder/folder1/file2.dmp
folder/folder1/file3.dmp
folder/folder1/file4.dmp
^Crsync error: received SIGINT, SIGTERM, or SIGHUP (code 20) at rsync.c(557) [sender=3.0.9]
[whois@serv1 ~]$
```